# Get variable to scope to other view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to allow visibility of variables that are populated in one view to also be used in another view. How do I accomplish this? The code for the two variables used in the 1st view and what I am trying to get in the 2nd view as below:

**Calendar View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Calendar")) 
     {
        <h2>Enter The Number Of Days To Display</h2>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new {id = "Date" })

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)
     }
```

**Update view**

```
// Convert both dates to milliseconds
var Date_milSec = model.Date.getTime();
var AddedDays_milSec = model.DaysToBeViewed.getTime();
```

I would like to take the variable 'Date' that is init in the Calendar view and use it to populate a TextBox on the Update View page. I have an Calendar.cshtml and an Update.cshtml.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: what do u want to achieve????

Comment: User selects a date from the date picker in the Calendar.cshtml view, that value populates a textbox in the update view.

Comment: ur update and calender views are separate???

Comment: I was lead to believe that was convention?

Comment: Sorry @kevin Schultz but i m not getting ur question..plz put some more code and explanation..

Comment: I believe the issue is scope because I get: Error 1 The name 'model' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: u cannot share a variable in two views in asp.net mvc...to achieve this u have to use some state management technique in asp.net mvc like tempdata or session

Comment: put into `viewdata` and pass to the view that you want